# Get word before and after dash '-' for multiple occurrences in a string

Tags: sql, regex, informatica

I am trying to parse foreign (Korean) addresses. Often the address would look like something like

```
Seoul, Gangnam-gu, South Korea
```

I want to be able to extract out: `Gangnam-gu` - Basically the word preceeding and proceeding the dash.

But there are times when there may be something like this

```
Seoul, Itaewon-dong, Gangnam-gu, South Korea
```

So in this case, I would want to be able to extract out BOTH: `Itaewon-dong` AND `Gangnam-gu`

I know that with REGEX I could pull out both words around the dash (`-`), though Im not sure how. And on top of that I dont know how to pull all the occurences.

Comment: You need to use [`REG_EXTRACT`](https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-0/transformation-language-reference/functions/reg_extract.html). You need to call it in a loop, starting from where the previous match ended. I'm not sure how you'd do that in Informatica.

Comment: What is your expected output? Are you looking for a single string, or an active transformation adding new rows to the data?

Answer (score 1):

this could serve:

```
([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z]+)
```

Cheers

Comment: This will match one occurrence, how do you get all of the matches in Informatica?

Comment: You should run it with the 'g' flag (global)

Comment: How do you specify that in `REG_EXTRACT()`?

Comment: Remember, this is SQL, there are no arrays. `REG_EXTRACT()` just returns a single string.

Comment: Can you show how you would use it in a `SELECT` query to get all the matches?

Comment: Couldn't tell. Saw the documentation but didn't see how to pass the flags.

Comment: Since it can only return one match string, that flag makes no sense in this context.

Answer (score 1):

you should try to use grep:

```
grep -oh '\w*-\w*' aa.txt
```

**result:**

```
Itaewon-dong
Gangnam-gu
```